# Grant O365 Mailbox Permission to a Managed Identity

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-logic-apps

Trying to get an Logic App to get email message details via Graph API because the O365 Outlook Connector does not provide the output I need but Graph API does (Internet message headers).

The Outlook connector creates an API Connection for authentication and that works great.

To call Graph API I am using the HTTP action and it supports Managed Identity, so I'm wondering:

1. Can I grant permission such that the Managed Identity can read a certain mailbox?
2. Can the HTTP action use an API Connection (similar to what the Outlook connector does)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Can I grant permission such that the Managed Identity can read a certain mailbox?

The managed identity is a service principal, which we can check it and its permissions in the Azure portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `Enterprise applications`. But we could not add new permissions in that, so we need to [create a new AD App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app) in the `App registrations`, [add credentials to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-credentials-to-your-web-application)
, then grant the `Mail.Read` application permission of Microsoft Graph API, refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-configure-app-access-web-apis#add-permissions-to-access-web-apis). The permission is to call this api [List messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs)(I suppose you want to use this api, if not, just follow the doc to find the application permission, add it.) At last, don't forget to click the `Grant admin consent` button.

[image]

In the logic app, use `Active Directory OAuth` for `Authentication`, `https://graph.microsoft.com/` for `Audience`, and specific the `URL`, `Client id`, `secret`, etc, what need to call the MS graph api. `xxx@microsoft.com` is the user principal name, also is the mailbox address. I am not sure I understand the *`read a certain mailbox`* in your question correctly enough, if you mean you want to grant the permission just for only one mailbox, I will say there is no such permission in Microsft graph.

[image]

> 2.Can the HTTP action use an API Connection (similar to what the Outlook connector does)?

There is no pre-bulit connector for http action, you could try the [Custom connectors in Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/custom-connector-overview).

Comment: Thanks Joy, that is very helpful.  Regarding 
"if you mean you want to grant the permission just for only one mailbox, I will say there is no such permission in Microsft graph."
That is what I want to do, I want to grant permission to just the one mailbox (a mailbox I control) because that is the least privilege but also because there's no way I'd get permission to read email for all mailboxes ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add that application role permission to the Managed Identity. It is not possible to do that using the Azure Portal. You can verify in the Azure Portal that the steps below worked though. This method saves you creating a principal yourself and removes the need for client id/secret bookkeeping.

When you use Powershell, it is possible to add the Mail.Read application role permission to a managed identity, be it a system managed or user managed identity. There are other ways of performing the same steps, e.g. Azure CLI. But below is what I know works and have used.

*The steps are usable for any identity and application with assignable app roles. So you can also add Sharepoint permissions to list sites, open an Excel sheet. But keep in mind that the Microsoft app roles are mostly all or nothing. It breaks the principle of least priviliged permissions.

**I would love to know a generic way to avoid breaking the principle.***

To assign an app role permission to a managed identity we need to know a couple of things:

the id of...

1. ...the managed identity (e.g. "logic-app-identity")
2. ...the application that has the application role (e.g. "Microsoft Graph")
3. ...the id of the application role to assign to the managed identity (e.g. "Mail.Read")

And then we can assign the app role to the managed identity.

#### Set up some variables for readability

```powershell
$managed_identity_name = "logic-app-identity"
$application_with_the_required_role_name = "Microsoft Graph"
$application_role_to_assign_name = "Mail.Read"
```

#### Use AzureAD module and login.

Use the AzureAd module from [here](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD/)

```powershell
Import-Module AzureAd
Connect-AzureAd #shows popup to login
```

#### 1. Get the managed identity id

```powershell
# filter first server side, and in case of multiple results, the where ensures a single result
# -All is necessary because a managed identity is a sort of service principal
$managed_identity_id = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -All $true -SearchString $managed_identity_name | where DisplayName -eq $managed_identity_name).ObjectId
```

#### 2. Get the application with the requested application roles

```powershell
# -SearchString on "Microsoft Graph" returns two results, therefore the where clause to ensure a single result
# storing the returned object, because it contains the approles array
$application_with_the_required_role = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -SearchString "Microsoft Graph" | where DisplayName -eq "Microsoft Graph")

# fun fact: the ObjectId of the "Microsoft Graph" application is always: 94d0e336-e38a-4bfc-9b21-8fbb74b6b835
$application_with_the_required_role_id = $application_with_the_required_role.ObjectId
```

#### 3. Get the application role id to assign to the managed identity

```powershell
# the required id is now simply called Id
# fun fact: the ObjectId of the "Mail.Read" app role is always: 810c84a8-4a9e-49e6-bf7d-12d183f40d01
$application_role_to_assign_id = ($application_with_the_required_role.AppRoles | where Value -eq $application_role_to_assign_name).Id
```

#### Assign the app role to the managed identity

```powershell
New-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $managed_identity_id -PrincipalId $managed_identity_id -ResourceId $application_with_the_required_role_id -Id $application_role_to_assign_id
```

#### BONUS: verify-ish the assignment

```powershell
# should list the assigned application to the identity, dig further for the specific app role
# (I don't know how :S)
Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignedTo -ObjectId $managed_identity_id | fl

# and the other way around to list the identities assigned to the application
Get-AzureADServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $application_with_the_required_role_id | fl
```